# Filtering changes of short length from a sequence (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

The title is a little vague, but I'm not sure how to put it differently. What I have is a pretty long array, say of length 10000, that contains the values 1,2 and 3. They are often located in long strings of the same number, such as

```
[1111111111122222222211111222222222233333332222]
```

The data denote 3 states of something, which are 1, 2 and 3. The only transitions possible are 1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, not 1 <-> 3.

In general the strings are very long, and it is thus unlikely to observe something like [111121111], where it changes to 2 for a single element and then back. However, due to errors in the measurements these things do come in, and I'm trying to find a way to filter them out in MATLAB. So what I want to do is remove all elements, for which the number of consecutive identical elements is smaller than some number X. If it is very difficult to do for general X, X = 1 is a very good start!

Personally, I have no idea how to tackle this. I imagine using diff can tell you where the elements change, and when they change again, en then somehow by denoting their indices you can find the length of the sequences. Then, using some if conditions, you can remove them. This should probably be done backwards, as the size of the array will change. I'm still trying to get something working with these things, but no success so far. Maybe someone could give me a hint?

Comment: What should happen to 111111112333333?

Comment: It should be come 11111111333333 in the case of X = 1.

Comment: Ok, but how do you decide whether the 2 becomes a 1 or a 3? Always a 1? Or always the preceding symbol?

Comment: Yes, this is something I definitely forgot to add. The symbol should be replaced by the preceding one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach 1** (uses `bsxfun`. Inefficient. I recommend second approach.<sup>1</sup> )

The following code detects the beginning of short runs. What to do then is not clear from your question (Remove those entries? Fill them with the preceding value?).

```
x = '1111111111122222222211111222222222233333332222'; %// data (string)
len = 5; %// runs of this length or shorter will be detected

ind = find(diff(x-'0')~=0) + 1; %// index of changes
mat = bsxfun(@minus, ind.', ind); %'// distance between changes
mat = tril(mat); %// only distance to *previous* changes, not to *later* changes
mat(mat==0) = NaN;
result = ind(any(mat<=len)); %// index of beginning of short runs
```

In this example the result is

```
result =
    21
```

Note that the last run is not considered. So in the example, even though the last run is shorter than `len`, it is not detected as too short. If you need to also detect that run, change the `ind` line to

```
ind = find([diff(x-'0') inf]~=0) + 1;
```

In this case,

```
result =
    21    43
```

---

**Approach 2** (uses `diff`. Much more efficient than approach 1.)

It sufficies to compare each index with the preceding index, instead of with all other indices as above. Also, as per comments, short runs need to be replaced with the preceding value; and last run should also be detected if it's short:

```
%// Data
x = '1111111111122222222211111222222222233333332222'; %// data (string)
len = 5; %// runs of this length or shorter will be detected

%// Detect beginning of short runs
ind = find([diff(x-'0') inf]~=0) + 1;
starts = ind(diff(ind)<=len); %// index of beginning of short runs

%// Replace short runs with preceding value
ind = [ind numel(x)+1]; %// extend ind in case last run was detected as short
for k = find(diff(ind)<=len)
    x(ind(k):ind(k+1)-1) = x(ind(k)-1); %// replace
end
```

---

<sup>1</sup>   <sub>Why do I keep approach 1, then? Well, it got me four upvotes before approach 2 ocurred to me, so there must be something to it (I suspect that has something to do with `bsxfun`...)</sub>

Comment: I was looking for some `bsxfun` approach myself!

Comment: Thank you for your help! The entries should ideally be replaced by the previous value, which I forgot to mention in the first point indeed. Also looking at the last sequence would be nice, but it is not essential. I'm going to have to look into bsxfun myself though, as I don't understand completely yet.

Comment: @user129412 `bsxfun(@minus, ind.', ind)` just computes the difference (`@minus`) between all combinations of values of `ind`. (When fed with a column vector `ind.'` and a row vector `ind`, `bsxfun` generates all such combinations)

Comment: I am running into an issue now though. I'm getting Error using bsxfun
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
This is for input strings of length 20000.

Comment: @user129412 Yes, `bsxfun` tries to build a 20000x20000 matrix in that case, which causes the error. For sizes that large you probably need to resort to a loop. What about @Divakar's answer?

Comment: I'll try and work with that yeah, although I have to figure out how to make that replace the values rather than remove.

Comment: @user129412 I found a much more efficient approach which avoids `bsxfun`. Please see edited answer

Comment: Thank you kindly! I was wondering though, result is not really used anywhere is it?

Comment: @user129412 No, `result` is not used. If you don't need it you can comment out that line. I've changed its name from `result` to `starts`, which is more meaningful

Answer (score 2):

This could be one approach -

```
%%// Input string
a1 = '111111111112222222221111122222222221111133333332222'

th = 10 %%// Less than or equal to 10 consecutive oocurances shall be removed

str1 = num2str(a1=='1','%1d')

t1 = strfind(['0' str1 '0'],'01')' %%//'
t2 = strfind(['0' str1 '0'],'10')' %%//'
t3 = [t1 t2-1]
t4 = t3([t2-t1]<=th,:)

ind1 = true(size(a1))
for k=1:size(t4,1)
  ind1(t4(k,1):t4(k,2))=false;
end
out = a1(ind1) %%// Output string
```

Output -

```
out =
11111111111222222222222222222233333332222
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure that works actually. I tried it with th = 1, and a1 = '112111322333122',  and nothing actually changes in the output. Moreover I'd like to actually have arrays rather than strings (that was a very bad usage of the term string on my part, I meant it in it's meaning as chain rather than the ACTUAL meaning, I apologize), but that it of course very easily changed

Comment: As commented in the demo codes - `th = 10 %%// Less than 10 consecutive oocurances shall be removed` Thus if you put `th=1`, nothing will change. If you have `a1` as a double array, it won't change much, just use `str1 = num2str(a1==1,'%1d')`.

Comment: That is my mistake entirely. th = 2 doesn't work either though, for that input.

Comment: ... And I made even more mistakes in my comment. I'm referring to char as string there.

Comment: haha dont worry! Well I just edited few things there. First off the way threshold is defined. Second was a bug fix. So try it out!

Comment: Hm, that seems to work, but it only filters out 'wrong' series of ones. That makes sense though, looking at the code. I should just repeat the 'middle' part for the other numbers to include that?

Comment: `wrong` series of ones? Not sure what you meant there. Yes, try it out  for other numbers. Just replace `1` with `2` there - `str1 = num2str(a1=='2','%1d')`, rest of the code stays good.

Comment: I meant that it only filters out the series of 1, that are too short, not of 2 and 3. But I think I managed to make it work for all three simultaneously, now I just need to look into converting matrices to char and char to matrices. Thanks!

Comment: Is you data originally in char type or double?

Comment: It's originally double

Comment: Use `str1 = num2str(a1==1,'%1d')` then as told earlier too, when `a1` is double.

Comment: Yeah, getting it into char is not the trouble, but getting back into an array is. It thinks that 11231312312 is just one number, while it would just be separate elements.

Comment: For getting back double, just subtract the ascii value of `0` or use `- '0'`

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help :) I should have been more clear in my question (and I will be from now on), but your solution was definitely helpful!

Comment: I'm trying of a way to modify this such that the values would be replaced by the previous value, rather than removed? This is something I didn't add in my original post, and I personally don't see how to add it in easily, so it's probably not going to be easy..

Comment: It would happen in the for loop, I can get that far, but I'm a little confused by all the logic stuff and the strings, I've really only worked with double type data in MATLAB before